# SHA-256 BigQuery function or UDF

Tags: google-bigquery, sha256

Does anyone have a UDF or know of plans to support SHA-256 in BigQuery?

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#syntax_16

Best,

Jeremy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below as an example

```
SELECT input, input_sha256 FROM JS(
(
  SELECT title AS input
  FROM [bigquery-public-data:hacker_news.stories]
  GROUP BY input
  LIMIT 40 
),
input,
"[ {'name': 'input', 'type': 'string'}, {'name': 'input_sha256', 'type': 'string'} ] ",

"function(row, emit) { 
  var CryptoJS=CryptoJS||function(h,s){var f={},g=f.lib={},q=function(){},m=g.Base={extend:function(a){q.prototype=this;var c=new q;a&&c.mixIn(a);c.hasOwnProperty('init')||(c.init=function(){c.$super.init.apply(this,arguments)});c.init.prototype=c;c.$super=this;return c},create:function(){var a=this.extend();a.init.apply(a,arguments);return a},init:function(){},mixIn:function(a){for(var c in a)a.hasOwnProperty(c)&&(this[c]=a[c]);a.hasOwnProperty('toString')&&(this.toString=a.toString)},clone:function(){return this.init.prototype.extend(this)}}, r=g.WordArray=m.extend({init:function(a,c){a=this.words=a||[];this.sigBytes=c!=s?c:4*a.length},toString:function(a){return(a||k).stringify(this)},concat:function(a){var c=this.words,d=a.words,b=this.sigBytes;a=a.sigBytes;this.clamp();if(b%4)for(var e=0;e<a;e++)c[b+e>>>2]|=(d[e>>>2]>>>24-8*(e%4)&255)<<24-8*((b+e)%4);else if(65535<d.length)for(e=0;e<a;e+=4)c[b+e>>>2]=d[e>>>2];else c.push.apply(c,d);this.sigBytes+=a;return this},clamp:function(){var a=this.words,c=this.sigBytes;a[c>>>2]&=4294967295<< 32-8*(c%4);a.length=h.ceil(c/4)},clone:function(){var a=m.clone.call(this);a.words=this.words.slice(0);return a},random:function(a){for(var c=[],d=0;d<a;d+=4)c.push(4294967296*h.random()|0);return new r.init(c,a)}}),l=f.enc={},k=l.Hex={stringify:function(a){var c=a.words;a=a.sigBytes;for(var d=[],b=0;b<a;b++){var e=c[b>>>2]>>>24-8*(b%4)&255;d.push((e>>>4).toString(16));d.push((e&15).toString(16))}return d.join('')},parse:function(a){for(var c=a.length,d=[],b=0;b<c;b+=2)d[b>>>3]|=parseInt(a.substr(b, 2),16)<<24-4*(b%8);return new r.init(d,c/2)}},n=l.Latin1={stringify:function(a){var c=a.words;a=a.sigBytes;for(var d=[],b=0;b<a;b++)d.push(String.fromCharCode(c[b>>>2]>>>24-8*(b%4)&255));return d.join('')},parse:function(a){for(var c=a.length,d=[],b=0;b<c;b++)d[b>>>2]|=(a.charCodeAt(b)&255)<<24-8*(b%4);return new r.init(d,c)}},j=l.Utf8={stringify:function(a){try{return decodeURIComponent(escape(n.stringify(a)))}catch(c){throw Error('Malformed UTF-8 data');}},parse:function(a){return n.parse(unescape(encodeURIComponent(a)))}}, u=g.BufferedBlockAlgorithm=m.extend({reset:function(){this._data=new r.init;this._nDataBytes=0},_append:function(a){'string'==typeof a&&(a=j.parse(a));this._data.concat(a);this._nDataBytes+=a.sigBytes},_process:function(a){var c=this._data,d=c.words,b=c.sigBytes,e=this.blockSize,f=b/(4*e),f=a?h.ceil(f):h.max((f|0)-this._minBufferSize,0);a=f*e;b=h.min(4*a,b);if(a){for(var g=0;g<a;g+=e)this._doProcessBlock(d,g);g=d.splice(0,a);c.sigBytes-=b}return new r.init(g,b)},clone:function(){var a=m.clone.call(this); a._data=this._data.clone();return a},_minBufferSize:0});g.Hasher=u.extend({cfg:m.extend(),init:function(a){this.cfg=this.cfg.extend(a);this.reset()},reset:function(){u.reset.call(this);this._doReset()},update:function(a){this._append(a);this._process();return this},finalize:function(a){a&&this._append(a);return this._doFinalize()},blockSize:16,_createHelper:function(a){return function(c,d){return(new a.init(d)).finalize(c)}},_createHmacHelper:function(a){return function(c,d){return(new t.HMAC.init(a, d)).finalize(c)}}});var t=f.algo={};return f}(Math); 
  (function(h){for(var s=CryptoJS,f=s.lib,g=f.WordArray,q=f.Hasher,f=s.algo,m=[],r=[],l=function(a){return 4294967296*(a-(a|0))|0},k=2,n=0;64>n;){var j;a:{j=k;for(var u=h.sqrt(j),t=2;t<=u;t++)if(!(j%t)){j=!1;break a}j=!0}j&&(8>n&&(m[n]=l(h.pow(k,0.5))),r[n]=l(h.pow(k,1/3)),n++);k++}var a=[],f=f.SHA256=q.extend({_doReset:function(){this._hash=new g.init(m.slice(0))},_doProcessBlock:function(c,d){for(var b=this._hash.words,e=b[0],f=b[1],g=b[2],j=b[3],h=b[4],m=b[5],n=b[6],q=b[7],p=0;64>p;p++){if(16>p)a[p]= c[d+p]|0;else{var k=a[p-15],l=a[p-2];a[p]=((k<<25|k>>>7)^(k<<14|k>>>18)^k>>>3)+a[p-7]+((l<<15|l>>>17)^(l<<13|l>>>19)^l>>>10)+a[p-16]}k=q+((h<<26|h>>>6)^(h<<21|h>>>11)^(h<<7|h>>>25))+(h&m^~h&n)+r[p]+a[p];l=((e<<30|e>>>2)^(e<<19|e>>>13)^(e<<10|e>>>22))+(e&f^e&g^f&g);q=n;n=m;m=h;h=j+k|0;j=g;g=f;f=e;e=k+l|0}b[0]=b[0]+e|0;b[1]=b[1]+f|0;b[2]=b[2]+g|0;b[3]=b[3]+j|0;b[4]=b[4]+h|0;b[5]=b[5]+m|0;b[6]=b[6]+n|0;b[7]=b[7]+q|0},_doFinalize:function(){var a=this._data,d=a.words,b=8*this._nDataBytes,e=8*a.sigBytes; d[e>>>5]|=128<<24-e%32;d[(e+64>>>9<<4)+14]=h.floor(b/4294967296);d[(e+64>>>9<<4)+15]=b;a.sigBytes=4*d.length;this._process();return this._hash},clone:function(){var a=q.clone.call(this);a._hash=this._hash.clone();return a}});s.SHA256=q._createHelper(f);s.HmacSHA256=q._createHmacHelper(f)})(Math); 
  (function(){var h=CryptoJS,j=h.lib.WordArray;h.enc.Base64={stringify:function(b){var e=b.words,f=b.sigBytes,c=this._map;b.clamp();b=[];for(var a=0;a<f;a+=3)for(var d=(e[a>>>2]>>>24-8*(a%4)&255)<<16|(e[a+1>>>2]>>>24-8*((a+1)%4)&255)<<8|e[a+2>>>2]>>>24-8*((a+2)%4)&255,g=0;4>g&&a+0.75*g<f;g++)b.push(c.charAt(d>>>6*(3-g)&63));if(e=c.charAt(64))for(;b.length%4;)b.push(e);return b.join('')},parse:function(b){var e=b.length,f=this._map,c=f.charAt(64);c&&(c=b.indexOf(c),-1!=c&&(e=c));for(var c=[],a=0,d=0;d< e;d++)if(d%4){var g=f.indexOf(b.charAt(d-1))<<2*(d%4),h=f.indexOf(b.charAt(d))>>>6-2*(d%4);c[a>>>2]|=(g|h)<<24-8*(a%4);a++}return j.create(c,a)},_map:'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/='}})(); 
  emit( { input: row.input, input_sha256: CryptoJS.SHA256(row.input).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex) } ); 
}" 
)
```

Comment: One quick comment - I'd recommend using the syntax documented at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions rather than the inline "js( ... )" syntax.  The inline syntax is explicitly undocumented and unsupported, and will be deprecated soon.  The deprecation notice will be going out in about a week to projects that are currently running queries using the syntax.

Comment: this is a little earlier than I expected to happen :o( - thank you for headsup!

Comment: You'll have about 2 months to migrate your jobs over before we deactivate it - we'll just be sending out notifications soon to let people know  :)

Comment: thank you! that is in line with what I was told before. thank you again for clearing this!

Comment: would be interesting to know why this was just down-voted!

Comment: What is the BigQuery alternative if this is deprecated?

Comment: @Praxiteles - BigQuery Standard SQL now (since today I think) supports SHA256 (as well as MD5, SHA1, SHA512). The documentation isn't live yet but they take either STRING or BYTES as input and return BYTES as output.

Answer (score 6):

This is now a feature in BigQuery using StandardSQL and here's how you return data as a string.

```
#StandardSQL
SELECT 
    TO_HEX(SHA256("Hello")) as hashed_string;
```

Output: *185f8db32271fe25f561a6fc938b2e264306ec304eda518007d1764826381969*

Comment: Thank you Perry. It is important to clarify that SHA256() is returning a Field containing Bytes.  
When using TO_HEX() you get String as a result.

Answer (score 2):

> 12-19-2016 Update

BigQuery Standard SQL is now supporting below functions:

```
•   MD5
•   SHA1
•   SHA256
•   SHA512
```

They take either STRING or BYTES as input and return BYTES as output.

see [for more details](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#sha256)