# SHA256 difference between HANA and Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, sha256, hana

I intend to compare huge data across HANA and Bigquery so was thinking of hashing the rows and reducing it and comparing it, however Sha256 of a row returns different values in HANA and Bigquery, PSB example: 
 
HANA (if i remove TO_BINARY i get into error):

```
SELECT cast(HASH_SHA256(TO_BINARY('Hello World')) AS VARCHAR) "HASH_STRING" FROM DUMMY;
```

Output:

> A591A6D40BF420404A011733CFB7B190D62C65BF0BCDA32B57B277D9AD9F146E

BigQuery:

```
SELECT SHA256(CAST('Hello World' as STRING)) as "HASH_STRING";
```

Output:

> pZGm1Av0IEBKARczz7exkNYsZb8LzaMrV7J32a2fFG4

I went through few HANA and Bigquery documentation (tried to change bigquery to use binary) but did not work

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer by referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37418403/sha-256-bigquery-function-or-udf#:%7E:text=this%20is%20now%20a%20feature%20in%20bigquery%20using%20standardsql%20and%20here%27s%20how%20you%20return%20data%20as%20a%20string.) post, below is the change:

```
SELECT upper(TO_HEX(SHA256(CAST('Hello World' as STRING)))) as hashvalue
```

> A591A6D40BF420404A011733CFB7B190D62C65BF0BCDA32B57B277D9AD9F146E

Comment: Both outputs express the same value, it's just that one is represented in hexadecimal (`a591a6d40bf420404a011733cfb7b190d62c65bf0bcda32b57b277d9ad9f146e`) and the other one in **Base64** (`pZGm1Av0IEBKARczz7exkNYsZb8LzaMrV7J32a2fFG4`). You can check yourself by using any converter from Hex to Base64 or vice versa.